# concateneate lines having same title

Tags: scala

I have the following issue
Given this list in input , I want to concateneate integers for each line having the same title,

```
val listIn= List("TitleB,Int,11,0",              
                  "TitleB,Int,1,0",               
                  "TitleB,Int,1,0",               
                   "TitleB,Int,3,0",
                   "TitleA,STR,3,0",
                    "TitleC,STR,4,5")
```

I wrote the following function

```
def sumB(list: List[String]): List[String] = {
  val itemPattern = raw"(.*)(\d+),(\d+)\s*".r
  list.foldLeft(ListMap.empty[String, (Int,Int)].withDefaultValue((0,0))) {
    case (line, stri) =>
      val itemPattern(k,i,j) = stri 
      val (a, b) = line(k)
      line.updated(k, (i.toInt + a, j.toInt + b))
  }.toList.map { case (k, (i, j)) => s"$k$i,$j" }
}
```

Expected output would be:

```
List("TitleB,Int,16,0",
     "TitleA,STR,3,0",
     "TitleC,STR,4,5")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking to preserve the order of the titles as they appear in the input data, I would suggest you to use LinkedHashMap with foldLeft as below

```
val finalResult = listIn.foldLeft(new mutable.LinkedHashMap[String, (String, String, Int, Int)]){ (x, y) => {

      val splitted = y.split(",")

      if(x.keySet.contains(Try(splitted(0)).getOrElse(""))){
        val oldTuple = x(Try(splitted(0)).getOrElse(""))
        x.update(Try(splitted(0)).getOrElse(""), (Try(splitted(0)).getOrElse(""), Try(splitted(1)).getOrElse(""), oldTuple._3+Try(splitted(2).toInt).getOrElse(0), oldTuple._4+Try(splitted(3).toInt).getOrElse(0)))
        x
      }
      else {
        x.put(Try(splitted(0)).getOrElse(""), (Try(splitted(0)).getOrElse(""), Try(splitted(1)).getOrElse(""), Try(splitted(2).toInt).getOrElse(0), Try(splitted(3).toInt).getOrElse(0)))
        x
      }
    }}.mapValues(iter => iter._1+","+iter._2+","+iter._3+","+iter._4).values.toList
```

`finalResult` should be your desired output

```
List("TitleB,Int,16,0", "TitleA,STR,3,0", "TitleC,STR,4,5")
```

Comment: hello You changed the order how to do to keep the same order please

Comment: currently no sorting is required. ? the same order of lines in input list shall be respected

Comment: Hello , no sorting shall be used , if the list in input starts with TitleB , this method gives us wrong results as it will start by TitleA. the same order of list in inout shall be preserved .

Comment: the order shall be the same as the input, we concateneate line s having the same name without modifying the order they have in the input list

Comment: I will modify my list in input so you can se what I mean

Comment: no same titles are 100% consecutive , there may be 2 similar titiles consecutive or 3 or 4 ( this number may be change and is not known ) is it more clear ?

Comment: Fantastic it worked , hope one day I will be as talented as you in scala :)

Comment: Hello The final result is a Map/ .Map[String,String], not a List[String], any help with this please

Comment: @scalacode, my mistake :) I have updated the answer with .values.toList please verify and if helpful you can upvote too